# Why is VSCodium failing to locate kernel32.lib?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, cmake, kernel32

I'm trying to build a CMake-based C project in VSCodium.

When I open the folder, CMake configuration fails, with the error being, apparently:

```
-- snip --
  LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'kernel32.lib' [C:\cygwin64\home\eyal\src\mine\printf\build\CMakeFiles\3.20.21032501-MSVC_2\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj]
-- snip --
```

Why is VSCode / CMake not setting the paths properly to find that file? I mean, it's some internal MSVC file, right?

Answer (score 1):

While you seem to have the MSVC compiler and its associated standard libraries - you may ctually missing that file, `kernel32.lib`. It is part of the "Windows SDK", which you can download via the MS Build Tools installer (e.g. from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019)) or the MS Visual Studio Installer. Just some MS confusion (and huge disk space wastage) to get used to.